# Compile-time, load-time, run-time: phases of... what?

Tags: runtime, compilation, terminology, vocabulary, load-time

Sorry for the confusing title :P

I'm sure I should know this but I always have trouble with terminology. I can't figure out the right word to put in the blank space in the following sentence:

> Different weaving strategies are
>   usually classified according to the
>   phase of _______________ at which they are
>   performed, resulting in the categories
>   *static weaving*, *load-time weaving*, *just-in-time weaving* and *run-time weaving*.

So, basically: compilation, load, run,... are phases of... what? The word eludes me!

Thanks so much.

Comment: Damn - you've got us all believing that there *is* a word that describes this, but that we just can't think of it ;)

Comment: Haha, I know, that's how I feel too! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Program lifetime" is the only term I can think of.

Comment: Yeah, lifecycle sounds best. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Binding is probably the word I'd put in there. It applies as much to computers as it does to the loom :-)

Answer (score 1):

Different weaving strategies are usually classified according to the phase of  "Processing"  at which they are performed, resulting in the categories static weaving, load-time weaving, just-in-time weaving and run-time weaving.

I also like Binding that Pax has mentioned before.

Comment: I'm torn between this one and "binding". Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could add value! :)
I know what you mean though. Both sound equally good to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are not phases of anything, but rather self-referencing descriptions of particular events.  What are lunch time and dinner time phases of?

"Different weaving strategies are usually classified according to when they are performed, ..."

Comment: I see what you mean and it's true that in the title I asked about compile-time, load-time, etc, but in the body of the question I ask "compilation, load, run,... are phases of... what?". Surely they're phases of something, aren't they?